# add library on makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I execute the guide of "Using a “Real” Cross-Compiler" descript on the [link](http://www.ev3dev.org/docs/tutorials/using-brickstrap-to-cross-compile/). In the botton of the guide there is a standard makefile. I write a simple program write in C and with the comand make it run. Now I would to write a program with the library "ev3c.h". How can I add this library in the makefile?

Comment: That's a header. Include it in your source. To link a library (libblah.a for example use -lblah as a compiler option

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. My path of ev3c.h is /home/daniele/ev3c/include. How can I insert this in makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using gcc or clang, pass `-I  /home/daniele/ev3c/include` to it in your recipe.
That'll allow you to `#include` from that path with `#include "someheader"`.

As far as Make-treatment of include files is concerned, they're usually implicit dependencies—that is you usually don't want to mention them in your dependencies explicitly, because compilers such as `clang` or `gcc` can detect them and add them to the appropriate Makefile rules for you.

`-MMD -MF somefile` allows you to do this kind of #include dependency detection with gcc or clang:

For example:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) -I /home/daniele/ev3c/include $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $< -MMD -MF $(patsubst %.o,%.o.d,$@)

-include $(wildcard *.o.d)
```

This will have the compiler detect include dependencies for each compiled c file and the `-include` line will add these dependencies to your Makefile so that if your C file includes `"foo.h"` and foo.h changes, `make` will trigger a recompile even if you don't mention `foo.h`  as an explicit dependency.

Answer (score -1):

Your .h file is header. Headers are included in the source code, not at compile time like libraries:

```
#include "ev3c.h"
```

for example.

A library has a different extension, like .a for example. You would add libev3c.a with:

```
-lev3c
```

in your makefile on the line that calls your compiler. However, you have a header, so simply add *#include "ev3c.h"* to the top of your source code (the .c file)

Comment: You probably also have to add `-I/home/daniele/ev3c/include` and perhaps `-L/home/daniele/ev3c/lib` to the command lines — where the path is from a comment, and might perhaps be handled by `EV3CDIR = ${HOME}/ev3c` as a macro and then use `${EV3CDIR}` in the make rules.